# A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'. > A problem occurred configuring project ':app'. > Cannot invoke method

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, gradle, apk

```
description: A new Flutter application.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.37+37

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  shared_preferences: ^0.5.7
  kf_drawer: ^1.1.2
  http: ^0.12.2
  charts_flutter: ^0.12.0
  intl: ^0.16.1
  percent_indicator: ^2.1.3
  table_calendar: ^2.3.1
  #smooth_page_indicator: ^0.2.0
  android_intent: ^0.3.7
  geolocator: ^5.3.0
  location: ^3.0.1
  trust_location: ^2.0.11
  permission_handler: ^3.2.1+1
  font_awesome_flutter: ^8.10.1
  url_launcher: ^5.7.10
  device_info: ^1.0.0
  firebase_messaging: ^7.0.3
  #flutter_local_notifications: ^1.4.4+1
  path_provider: ^1.6.11
  #sqflite: ^1.3.0
  #upgrader: ^2.8.2
  package_info: ^0.4.0+16

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
  open_appstore: ^1.0.2
  cached_network_image: ^2.5.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/icons/ic_app_icon.png
    - assets/pict/ic_splash_screen.jpg
    - assets/icons/ic_splash_screen_logo.png


  fonts:
    - family: Nunito
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/Nunito-Regular.ttf

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #  - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #  - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

I have upgaded my flutter version to latest.
When I try to run this project in Android emulator, it's giving me this error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/Users/jeckymodi/Downloads/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 462

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
   > Cannot invoke method afterEvaluate() on null object

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

i am using latest JDK and latest gradle version.

I don't know what's issue there.
Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Build using the command flutter build -v apk, you will get hints about the error